# Conjugation action of $Gal(\bar{s}/s)$ on the tame ramification group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, etale-cohomology, local-fields

There is a statement in SGA 7-1 Exposé 1 (P. Deligne, *Résumé des premiers exposés de A. Grothendieck*, [pdf of SGA7-1](http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/pdf/sga7-1.pdf)), (0.3.1):

> $S$ is a Henselian trait (i.e. the spectrum of a henselian discrete valuation ring), $\eta$, $s$, $V$, $\bar{V}$, $\bar{\eta}$, $\bar{s}$ as usual, and $1\to I\to Gal(\bar{\eta}/\eta) \to Gal(\bar{s}/s) \to 1$. $p$ is a characteristic of the residue field of $s$, $P$ be the pro-$p$ part of $I$, then the tame ramification group $I/P$ is canonically isomorphic to $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1)(k(\bar{s}))$.
>
> Then the action of $Gal(\bar{s}/s)$ on $I/P$ can be identified with the natural action of $Gal(\bar{s}/s)$ on $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1)(k(\bar{s}))$.

It refers to Serre's *Local Fields* for proofs, but I cannot come up with a proof of this statement out of the this reference. Can somebody elaborate on this, or refer to a relevant section of the book?